# django get related foreign key in template

Tags: django

I need to display in template post and username which wrote this post. Model "post" have ForeignKey to user.

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ post.user_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.user_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.post_user.user_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.post_content }}</td>                
    </tr>
{% endfor %}



class user(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class post(models.Model):
        post_content = models.CharField(max_length=65000)
        post_user = models.ForeignKey(user)
```

none of way which i tried does not work

Answer (score 5):

`{{ post.post_user.user_name }}` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

`<td>{{ post.post_user.user_name }}</td>` Should be the winner.

What is outputted for each of those options?

Try using the `|pprint` filter to see what is going on:

```
{{ post|pprint }}
{{ post.post_user|pprint }}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ post|pprint }}
{{ post.post_user|pprint }}
{{ post.post_user.user_name|pprint }}
{{ post|pprint }}
```

`<post: post object> 
<user: user object> 
'1' 
<post: post object>`

that's my views

```
try:
            post_list = post.objects.select_related().filter(post_thread_id = thread_obj.id).order_by('-post_date')
        except:
            post_list = False                
        c = {
            'thread': thread_obj,
            'post_list': post_list,
            'user_login' : user_login,
            'user_name' : user_name, // user name which is login
            }
        c.update(csrf(request))  
        return render_to_response("show_thread.html", c)
```